# How to validate properties in 2 different situations in mvc 2 app?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-validation

please help me with asp.net MVC 2 application.

I have class:

```
public class Account
{
    [Required(....)]
    [RegularExpression("....")]
    public string AccountCode{ get; set; } 

    public string BankName{ get;  set; } 
}
```

And another one:

```
public class BankPageModel
{
    public bool AccountRequired {get; set; }
    public Account NewAccount {get;set;}
}
```

Imagine I have page and form on it with 2 text boxes (AccountCode and BankName) and check box (AccountRequired). So when I post the form, if check box is checked, I want to validate AccountCode to be required and to fit regular expression. But if it is not checked, I just want to ignore those text boxes and to post the form. But Required and RegularExpression attributes cannot be used then, they are preventing it. I could make class attribute, but what if I have more textboxes with similar validation, I don't want to make class attribute for each of them...
What do you think? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Cemsha....you could do this in JavaScript.  Have a function that is called on the onclick event of your Submit button.  That function looks at the check box and either validates or not based on check box

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use server (mvc) validation. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this on the server side, is to have your model implement **IValidatableObject** and then do the following:

```
public class BankPageModel : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.IValidatableObject
{
    public bool AccountRequired { get; set; }
    public Account NewAccount { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // only perform validation here if account required is checked
        if (this.AccountRequired)
        {
            // check your regex here for account
            if (!RegEx.IsMatch(this.NewAccount.AccountCode, "EXPRESSION"))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doing things this way helps keep your controllers lean and encapsulates all validation logic in your model.  This method could also be verified client side with [unobtrusive javascript](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/javascript/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript).

Comment: so you suggest making a custom one of these for every custom validation scenario you encounter? Sounds like a whole lot of little class files around that are very tightly coupled to your model (might have to change both when you make a change) but it does a nice job of encapsulation for unit testing. Interesting

Comment: @JohnCulviner Well that depends on the developer really.  Personally I like to have my controllers lean so if (ModelState.IsValid) { do this } else { do that } - this link elaborates further: http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2008/12/03/the-fat-controller/ I typically don't use data annotations on my model properties, instead I do ALL of my model validation in the Validate override of IValidatableObject.  I feel it gives me far more flexibility over validating, and I find it easier to read.  But as I say, this is my preference - I've worked with developers who hate models and love controllers.

Comment: @JohnCulviner oh, just to clarify having re-read your comment.  I wouldn't have this validation code in a separate file, it would be contained within the model class itself as an overridden method.  So each model object in your project would have its own, self-contained validation logic which would be included in the ModelState.IsValid check in your controller.  You'd just perform checks in the order you need to, and yield return the results.  This would appear as a list of issues to your user on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use DataAnnotations to perform validation, they just make things easier for common validation scenarios (and you can get client side JavaScript validation for free too).

You can always perform the validation in C# code in your Controller action like below:

```
public ViewResult BankPageAdd(BankPageModel model)
{
    if(model.AccountRequired &&
        (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.Account.AccountCode) || !Regex.IsMatch(model.Account.AccountCode, "PATTERN HERE"))
        ModelState.AddModelError("NewAccount.AccountCode", "ERROR MESSAGE HERE");

    //remainder of your controller action code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And the javaScript version:

```
function validateAccountCode() {
        var bCkd = document.getElementById("ckbxAccountRequired").checked;

        if (bCkd) {
           var accountCode = document.forms[0].elements["AccountCode"].value;
            if(!accountCode.match(yourRegEx) || accountCode==""){
               alert('Please fill in the Account Code');
               return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```